# Nearer - is it a preposition?

Tags: grammar

"Near" can be a preposition, an adjective or an adverb.
Of course, as an adverb or adjective, you can put it in the comparative: *nearer*.

But can you do so when you use "near" as a preposition?

*My house is nearer the school than yours.*

is a grammatically correct sentence, even though I would prefer

*is nearer TO the school*

So my question is: is "nearer" really a preposition in the comparative, or is the real preposition "to", but there's an ellipsis, and only "nearer" is left, and then it would be an adverb.

Thank you for your input and your answers.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Yes, it's a preposition, one of just a few that inflect for grade: "near" / "nearer" / "nearest". The "to" is optional with "near". In "nearer to the school", the preposition "nearer" selects a _to_ PP. "Near" is never an adverb, but it can also be an adjective as in, for example, "near relative".

Comment: Thank you! According to Macmillan dictionary, it is also an adverb: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/near_1

Comment: Yes, most dictionaries do, but they are wrong. In modern grammar, it is a preposition. Here's a link to a forward-thinking dictionary that analyses it as prep: [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/near)